# VB6 SQL Field Data to ListView box?

Tags: vb6

I need to add SQl Data from a field to a ListView box. This is what I have at the moment. I am just unsure on how to add the data to the listview box as a list.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ConnectionObj As ADODB.Connection
Set ConnectionObj = New ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim sqlstr As String



ConnectionObj.CursorLocation = adUSeClient
ConnectionObj.Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;dsn=SVR-TESTSQL-01_SQL2008R2;DATABASE=WebVanilla;uid=WebUser;pwd=1209sawedxz1209;"

sqlstr = "select top 10 * from DeFactoUser.F_GL_Events"

rs.Open sqlstr, ConnectionObj, adOpenKeyset

MsgBox "Connected" & rs.RecordCount


If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    'Add to list view box command Data = rs.Fields(0)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If
```

Comment: One uses a adodb.recordset; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141412(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: I now have it outputting the data from column 1 into a bunch of message boxes. I just need to get it all into a listbox.

Comment: I don't understand the question, then; it's not about running a SQL SELECT query at all, but about adding the results to a ListBox. Edit your question then to ask that instead (unless you get an answer related to the SELECT - once you start getting answers, you can't change the meaning of the question). Instead of `MsgBox i & rs(0)`, just use `ListBox.Add rs(0)` and remove the counter if you don't need it.

Comment: I have just done that before you posted and that works. Now I just need to split the listbox up an have the different data collumms. Working on this now.